# Loading .so file with duplicated classes that have already been loaded from another .so file on Android?

Tags: android, c++, shared-libraries, native

Alright so I realize that this is both an odd and niche question, but I'm hoping someone will know the answer :)

I am currently working with an Android project that requires loading a closed-source `.so` native library. Let's call it `libX.so`. Now, `libX.so` happens to also depend on and have a copy of `libY.so` (which happens to be open source) built inside of it.

However, I would now like to build my own native library; we'll call it `libZ.so`. But, `libZ.so` is also going to depend on `libY.so`. So the question then becomes, **what will happen when I try to load `libZ.so` after `libX.so` has already been loaded?** Will things explode because both `libX.so` and `libZ.so` contain `libY.so` inside of them?

Basically, I don't want to waste a bunch of time building `libZ.so` if I can't have it loaded at the same time as `libX.so`. (I should note that both `libX.so` and `libZ.so` would be loaded by using `System.loadLibrary()` from Java).

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Seems the more challenging aspect is what if `libY.so` is two different versions of same - can you rule that out?

Comment: Will not pose any problem if it's the same `libY.so`. Otherwise nothing would work (all C++ libraries depend on the same C++ runtime libraries if using shared ones).

Comment: @Andy well..... uh... I don't know. I'm also not sure that `libX.so` has an *entire* copy of `libY.so` inside of it; I think the authors may have just copied a few source files of libY into it, because by doing a `strings` search on `libX.so`, I was able to find strings that indicate the author had some of the source files from libY in his `/src/main/cpp/` folder....

Comment: If `libX.so` does not expose anything from libY.sp then nothing will happen. Otherwise horrible things may happen.

Comment: Ok update, so I did `strings libX.so | grep ".so"` and it came back with `libC.so, libdl.so, libc++_shared.so, libjnigraphics.so, liblog.so, libGLESv2.so, libm.so, libRS.so, libRSSupport.so`, none of which are `libY.so`, so does that confirm the author just copied some source files from libY? And if so, does that mean I'm OK to proceed?